# Res.send trigger before recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js

My response is send before my recursive function push value on array. For now I am implementing the Timeout function. By this I am getting the value. But This is not a right approach. If Anyone have better approach or idea then suggest me. Any help is really appreciated.

```
var likepostidholder = [];

db.collection.find({}).sort({'createdate': -1}).limit(20).exec(function(error, data) {
 if(error){
  console.log(error)
} else {
  //create Recursive function which acts like loop
  var x = 0;
  var datalength = data.length;
  var recursiveFunction = function(length) {
    if (length > 0) {
      //I think There is some issue under this Db query.
 // Because if I console.log(x) then it returns the last number. If I write same console outside this Activity.find() query block then it returns all length one by one.
      Activity.find({'parentpost_id': data[x]._id}, {likes: {$elemMatch: {'userid': req.body.userid }}}, function(err, response){
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
   } else {
     if(response.length !== 0) {
        if(response[0].likes.length == 1) {                                              
              likepostidholder.push(response[0]._id);
        }
     }

   }
});
     x++;
     return recursiveFunction(length - 1);
   } else {
     console.log('now my job is done');
     return length;
   }
  }
  recursiveFunction(datalength);
  setTimeout(function(e){
    res.send({"error":"false", "status":"200", 'likepostid': likepostidholder});
 },500);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the request in the break condition of your recursive function, something like so :

Your recursive function perform an async no blocking task `Activity.find` Nodejs don't wait for this task to end before processing the next chunk of code.

```
var likepostidholder = [];

db.collection.find({}).sort({'createdate': -1}).limit(20).exec(function(error, data) {
 if(error){
  console.log(error)
} else {
  //create Recursive function which acts like loop
  var x = 0;
  var datalength = data.length;
  var recursiveFunction = function(length) {
    if (length > 0) {
     //I think There is some issue under this Db query.
     // Because if I console.log(x) then it returns the last number. If I write same console outside this Activity.find() query block then it returns all length one by one.
      Activity.find({'parentpost_id': data[x]._id}, {likes: {$elemMatch: {'userid': req.body.userid }}}, function(err, response){
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
   } else {
     if(response.length !== 0) {
        if(response[0].likes.length == 1) {                                              
              likepostidholder.push(response[0]._id);
        }
     }

   }
});
     x++;
     return recursiveFunction(length - 1);
   } else {
     console.log('now my job is done');
     res.send({"error":"false", "status":"200", 'likepostid': likepostidholder});
     return length;
   }
  }
  recursiveFunction(datalength);
}
});
```

Comment: Dear It not work there. It return the blank array. (By your described way). If I add setTimeout Function then it works there as I mentioned earlier